# iOS app made with Unity, how to keep using Admob without ATT prompt

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, apptrackingtransparency, skadnetwork

I use only Admob to serve ads on my iOS apps made with Unity. I don't want to display AppTrackingTransparency prompt since most users would reply to NOT be tracked.

I would like to:

1. keep using Admob
2. not using IFDA but only the new SKADNetwork

In short, I want my app to serve ads as if the user answered NO the to ATT prompt (since this is what's going to happen anyway)

How do I accomplish this with Unity?
Is it enough to use the following code?

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .AddExtra("npa", "1")
        .Build();
```

If I use the above code, can I fill the App Privacy Section stating that my apps are not tracking users?

In the the following page:
https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/ios14
I can read:
"If you decide to include App Tracking Transparency (ATT) in your app..."
So according to Google, including ATT is an option... how exactly do I choose not to include it AND keep using Admob?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty actual topic now since iOS 14.5 release. Let's sort some things out to proceed:

1. According to the updated Apple Terms and Conditions, you **must** show ATT popup to the users who use iOS 14.5. This is an Apple requirement with which I would not recommend to trick;
2. If your app uses any of the Ad Network and doesn't show an ATT popup, you will be rejected on the App Review stage when you try to release an update. You really have a small chance to be lucky and pass it, but most probably you'll not;
3. If the user blocks tracking, it doesn't mean you'll not show ads and lose money. Just to be clear: **you are allowed to show ads even if a user blocks the tracking**. You just need to use Ad Network API/SDK accordingly to not pass the device’s advertising identifier.

To support an ATT status with AdMob in Unity, you need to use an AdMob plugin for Unity of version at least 5.4.0. I'm attaching a link on official releases on GitHub with description and usage samples:
[AdMob plugin releases for Unity](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/releases/tag/v5.4.0).

In summary: consider not ignoring the Apple requirements, because it will directly affect your app. They always check your app manually before each release and track how your app meets their requirements, especially now, in the first week of iOS 14.5 public release.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not trying in any way to ignore or circumvent Apple rules. In the email that Apple sent me I can read: apps on the App Store must use AppTrackingTransparency [...] If you're already working on implementing the framework, we appreciate your efforts to provide transparency and choice to users. IF NOT, AND YOUR APP CONTINUES TO TRACK USERS, your next submission must implement AppTrackingTransparency to request the user’s permission to track them.
So ATT is mandatory only IF I track users, right?

Comment: Everything is correct. So just update your AdMob plugin for Unity with the version I mentioned in a post and use an expanded functionality of their SDK to correspond to these requirements. They have samples under a link in a post. Hope it helps!

Comment: It seems also that Google itself is not going to show ATT in its own apps. Source: https://www.iphonehacks.com/2021/01/google-app-tracking-pop-up-ios-14.html

Comment: What do you mean by "and use an expanded functionality of their SDK to correspond to these requirements" ?

Comment: What exactly must be configured in Admob when the user opts out of tracking ?